# Passing value from a jquery slider into Django views.py

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

How can I pass a value selected from a jQuery slider into Django views.py. Namely I've made a slider using (which probably needs to be edited to do what I want):

```
$(function() {
 $( ".slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  value: 0.3,
  step: 0.05,
 })
});
```

with the relevant html:

```
<form method="get"> 
<div name="slider" class="slider"></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When the user hits the submit button I would like to pass the value in the slider to views.py using something like:

```
value = request.GET['slider']
```

I've seen similar questions online, however, I'm new to web development and therefore don't quite understand how to adapt them to my case.

Comment: What are the advantages of using `post` here since it won't be editing the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider isn't attached to a form control so it won't get passed to the server. Try:

```
$(function() {
 $( ".slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  value: 0.3,
  step: 0.05,
  slide: function(event, elt) {
    $("#slider_control").val(elt.value);
  }
 })
});
```

Also add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="slider_control" id="slider_control" />
```

You'll get the value in as `slider_control` -- you can modify if you wish, of course.